# Quartz Job in a Grails Application being triggered three times

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

I have the next Quartz Job in a Grails Application. The job calculates some stats and sends and email with these stats. I want the job to execute everyday at 7 o'clock.

**My problem is the job istriggered three times every day instead of just once.**

```
class DailyEmailJob  {
    def eventService 

    static triggers = {
        cron name: 'emailTrigger', cronExpression: "0 0 7 * * ?"
    }

    def execute() {
        eventService.send24StatsEmail()
    }
}
```

I am hosting the Grails application in Apache Tomcat/7.0.35, running Grails 2.2.1 and quartz-1.0-RC6

Comment: Where are you hosting it? I have experienced similar issues...

Comment: Is the app installed on just one app server?

Comment: I am hosting in it in Rimuhosting.com in VPS. The application is just installed in one tomcat

Comment: Sorry for the late follow-up. The only theory I have is that you may have three instances running. I have an application deployed on Heroku with 2 dynos, before when I only had one I only got one mail.

Comment: As a suggestion use the new QUARTZ2 PLUGIN http://grails.org/plugin/quartz2  ... quartz 1 plugin is obsolete and bogus

Comment: What are the other times it triggers other than 7 AM?

Comment: Go with @FabianoTaioli , cause I've used Quartz 2.0 and never faced such an issue, though the project was on .NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cron expression looks OK.  Tomcat's auto-deployment features may be the culprit. For some suggestions, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11990221

Comment: I added a deployOnStartup="false"
autoDeploy="false" and today it trigger just twice. Could it because I have the war and directory under $CATALINA_HOME/webapps

Comment: Yes, that could explain it. I believe that the behavior also depends on how your application's `Context` is defined (ie in `server.xml`? in its own `.xml` file under `conf\Catalina\localhost`?)  In any case, try moving your .war file out of webapps; I believe that will help.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and I'm not sure if this is the cause.. My job always triggers *three* times. Why not *two* or *four*? @SergiodelAmo

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

The below analysis does **not** hold good in this scenario. This was only a hypothesis based on raw misunderstood facts. If advised, I can remove the answer.

**END**

I hope I can answer to my own question I asked in the comment.

"*What are the times it triggers other than 7 AM?*"

Is it **7 AM**, **2 PM** and **9 PM** ?

**Reason:**

- Refer to the version of `quartz` plugin [quartz-1.0-RC6] which uses `org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:1.8.4`. Refer [BuildConfig.groovy from Github](https://github.com/nebolsin/grails-quartz/blob/master/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy).
- Follow `CronExpression` API from the corressponding [Javadoc](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/1.8.5/).

**Highlighting the important verbiage**:-

"*The '/' character is used to specify increments. For example "0/15" in the seconds field means "the seconds 0, 15, 30, and 45". And "5/15" in the seconds field means "the seconds 5, 20, 35, and 50". Specifying '*' before the '/' is equivalent to specifying 0 is the value to start with. Essentially, for each field in the expression, there is a set of numbers that can be turned on or off. For seconds and minutes, the numbers range from 0 to 59. For hours 0 to 23, for days of the month 0 to 31, and for months 1 to 12. **The "/" character simply helps you turn on every "nth" value in the given set. Thus "7/6" in the month field only turns on month "7", it does NOT mean every 6th month, please note that subtlety.***"

In your case the cron expression: `"0 0 7 * * ?"` results in running the job every 7 hours in 24 hours (A day) resulting in running at 7 am , (7 + 7) 2 PM, (7 + 7 + 7) 9 PM.

This latest docs from `quartz-scheduler.org` say otherwise. Have a look at the examples [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger). Also study the "Special Character /".

Based on my tests on `seconds` and `minutes` [I did not want to wait for 24 hours to test :)], I strongly think the below `cronExpression` will work and trigger the `execute()` at exactly `7:00 Hrs` every day:

**Answer:**

1. `"0 0 7/23 * * ?"` [Run the job every 24 hours starting at the 7th hour 0th minute and 0th Second of the day]
2. `"0 0 0/23,7 * * ?"` [Synonymous to answer 1 but less verbose.]

Let know your test results. I strongly believe this will work. I am also going to set the scheduler up for the day/night in order to test results after 24 hours (I do not want to tamper the JVM clock in order to achieve a clear result, although I successfully tested doing the same tamper.). Will post results of my actual test.

Comment: It does not triggers at three different times. It triggers at 7:00 sharp three times in a couple of seconds

Comment: The cron expression is perfect, checked as per the docs that you mentioned also, don't mislead.
Try at http://www.cronmaker.com/

Comment: Have you used the grails quartz plugin yet?

Answer (score 1):

This is what the docs say

Either Day-of-Week or Day-of-Month must be "?", or you will get an error since support by the underlying library is not complete. So you can't specify both fields, nor leave both as the all values wildcard "*"; this is a departure from the unix crontab specification.

Hope that helps